# PHP Array - Recursivo

Tags: php, array, arraylist, recursión

Estoy intentando generar un árbol simple con links obteniendo los datos de un accesos ftp.

Lo único que me falta es obtener el nombre del parent en el child, para generar una URL correcta.

Hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente:

```
function dirToArray($dir = 'ftp://xxx:xxx@xxx/www/manuales/manuales-general/') {
   $result = array();
   $cdir = scandir($dir);
   foreach ($cdir as $key => $value){
      if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))){
         if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)){
            $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
         } else {
            $result[] = $value;
         }
      }
   }
   return $result;
}
$array = dirToArray();
function makeList($array) {
   $inicio = '';
      foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
         $get_link = '<a href="'.$k.makeList($v).'/'.$v.'">'.$v.'</a>';
         $inicio .= '<li>'.((is_array($v)) ? $k.makeList($v) : $get_link).'</li>';
      }
   return '<ul>'.$inicio.'</ul>';
}
echo makeList($array);
```

Y me muestra lo siguiente:

- Manuales-1

  - [archivo_1.pdf](/archivo_1.pdf)
  - [archivo_2.pdf](/archivo_2.pdf)
- Manuales-2

  - [archivo_1.pdf](/archivo_1.pdf)
  - [archivo_2.pdf](/archivo_2.pdf)
- Manuales-3

  - [archivo_1.pdf](/archivo_1.pdf)
  - [archivo_2.pdf](/archivo_2.pdf)

Como se puede observar, la URL no es del todo correcta, le falta el nombre de la carpeta principal.

El array es el siguiente:

```
array(3) {
  ["manuales-1"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "archivo_1.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "archivo_1.pdf"
  }
  ["manuales-2"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "archivo_1.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "archivo_2.pdf"
  }
  ["manuales-3"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "archivo_1.pdf"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "archivo_2.pdf"
  }
}
```

Me gustaría que se vea así:

- Manuales-1

  - [archivo_1.pdf](/manuales-1/archivo_1.pdf)
  - [archivo_2.pdf](/manuales-1/archivo_2.pdf)
- Manuales-2

  - [archivo_1.pdf](/manuales-2/archivo_1.pdf)
  - [archivo_2.pdf](/manuales-2/archivo_2.pdf)
  ...

Comment: Podrías mostrarme un ejemplo? No logro mostrarlo correctamente ya que el array no tiene índices, sólo los nombres directamente.

Comment: Creo que no había comprendido tu pregunta... Quieres recorrer de manera recursiva los archivos y directorios que están dentro de un directorio principal para crear una lista. Para ello puedes usar `scandir` de `php`. [Aquí la docu](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.scandir.php). Revisa los comentarios, hay varios ejemplos que te pueden servir.

Comment: Sí, de allí es donde traigo el primer array. Quizá estoy haciendo algo mal. Acabo de editar la pregunta con esa primera parte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo al arreglo que muestras en la pregunta, solo hay un nivel de carpetas y, por tanto, no necesitas recursividad, quedando la función con un par de ciclos, uno para directorios y otro para archivos:

```
function makeList($array = []) {
   // ¿El arreglo está vacío?
   if(empty($array)) {
       return '<p>No hay archivos para mostrar.</p>';
   }
   // Se crea la lista general
   $ret = '<ul>';
   // La clave de cada elemento es el directorio
   foreach($array as $dir => $files) {
       // Elemento de lista con nombre de directorio e inicio de sublista
       $ret .= "<li>$dir<ul>";
       // Recorrer archivos del directorio actual, no se necesita clave (índice)
       foreach($files as $file) {
           // Crear enlace para archivo, incluyendo ruta
           $ret .= "<li><a href=\"/$dir/$file\">$file</a></li>";
       }
       // Se cierra la lista del directorio
       $ret .= "</li></ul>
   }
   // Se cierra la lista general
   $ret .= '</ul>';
   return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Era justo lo que estaba necesitando. Muchas gracias por la aportación. En el caso que tenga un nivel más alguna carpeta, sería volver a hacer un foreach de tercer nivel cierto? O en ese caso cambiaría a recursivo?

Comment: @MarcelCL, sí hay más niveles sí debe ser una función recursiva, pero primero debes replantear la lógica para obtener los archivos y armar el arreglo.